# Using purrr's map on nested lubridate classes

Tags: r, lubridate, purrr

I'm trying to use `map` on a nested tibble for a non-standard class, specifically `lubridate`'s `interval()` result.  I can't seem to get it to `unnest()` in the correct class:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.4
require(lubridate)
#> Loading required package: lubridate
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16073, 16073, 16210, 16286, 
                                  16486, 16498, 16518, 16539, 16618, 16426, 16496, 16588, 16602, 
                                  16602, 16629, 16654, 16714, 16769, 16776, 17379), class = "Date"), 
               id = c(8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 
                      8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 
                      8843)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                      -20L), .Names = c("date", "id"))

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(date_range = map(data, ~interval(min(.x$date), max(.x$date)))) %>% 
  unnest(date_range)
#> Warning in combine_all(args[[1]]): Vectorizing 'Interval' elements may not
#> preserve their attributes
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>      id data              date_range
#>   <dbl> <list>                 <dbl>
#> 1  8843 <tibble [20 × 1]>  112838400
```

Created on 2018-07-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Is there any way to use map with non-standard classes, or is that still not supported?

Edit (update):

This produces what I want, but does so in an inefficient way. I'm hoping to learn how to do this correctly even though I have a workaround:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(date_min = map(data, ~min(.x$date)),
         date_max = map(data, ~max(.x$date))) %>% 
  unnest(date_min, date_max) %>% 
  mutate(date_range = interval(date_min, date_max))
```

Comment: I think `map` is doing what you expect, to return a list of `Interval` objects, but it is `unnest()` that is forcing those intervals to numeric. `?unnest` says it will work on list-columns that can be atomic vectors, lists, or data frames, but doesn't say anything about working `S4 objects` like `Interval`s, thus the cohercing (I'm guessing)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the poster's comments, I've tried to use this as an example of the use of `list-columns` rather than a solution to a specific problem. The first step forms a `list-column` containing a `tibble` of dates grouped by `id`.  The second step creates an intermediate `list-column` containing an interval object.  The last step makes simplified atomic vectors using accessor functions for the interval object.

```
   df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(16073, 16073, 16210, 16286, 
                                        16486, 16498, 16518, 16539, 16618, 16426, 16496, 16588, 16602, 
                                        16602, 16629, 16654, 16714, 16769, 16776, 17379), class = "Date"), 
                     id = c(8840, 8840, 8840, 8840, 8840, 8840, 8840, 8840, 8840, 
                            8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 8843, 
                            8843)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                     row.names = c(NA, -20L), .Names = c("date", "id"))
#
#   Example of three steps of list-column pipeline 
#
  df_int <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    nest(date, .key="date_data")  %>%                       # step 1: create data list-column 
    mutate( date_range = map(.x=date_data,                  # step 2: create intermediate list-columns
                        ~interval(min(.x$date), max(.x$date))) ) %>%
    mutate(start = map(date_range, int_start),              # step 3: simplify the list-columns back down to atomic vectors
           length = map_dbl(date_range, int_length) ) %>%   
    unnest(start, length)
```

which gives

```
df_int
# A tibble: 2 x 5
     id date_data         date_range     start                 length
  <dbl> <list>            <list>         <dttm>                 <dbl>
1  8840 <tibble [9 x 1]>  <S4: Interval> 2014-01-03 00:00:00 47088000
2  8843 <tibble [11 x 1]> <S4: Interval> 2014-12-22 00:00:00 82339200
```

The result is a single tibble grouped by identifier containing the original data, the intermediate object, and the simplified regular data which can be used in further processing.

For a complete explanation, see Hadley's "R for Data Science", especially the sections on List-Columns in Chapter 20.

**Special case of `interval`**

`interval` is a special case because it accepts vectors for its arguments `start` and `end` and produces an `interval` object containing multiple intervals
This allows us to do the following:

```
#  Use summarize to form the list-column with dates
#     and calculate the start and end dates as vectors for each id
#
  df_int2 <- df %>%
            group_by(id) %>%
            summarize( data = list(tibble(date)),
                       start_date = min(date),
                       end_date = max(date))
#
#   summarize has returned the grouped dates as a list of tibbles 
#           and has removed the grouping on id.  
#   mutate can then use the vectors start_date and end_date 
#     in interval to calcuate an interval object containing the two intervals
#
  df_int2 <- df_int2 %>% mutate(date_range = interval(start_date, end_date))
#
```

Comment: Dropping `unnest()` was actually how I started.  The problem is that it leaves the result as a single-item list.  Since the `interval()` result contains the start value already, it seems redundant to have a second map call to access it.

Comment: I've updated my answer above.  I've assumed that you're interested in obtaining  `interval` objects and not just calculating the min and max dates for each group.

Comment: Thanks.  This solves the immediate problem (as does my edit) but I'm really after a solution to unnesting non-standard classes.

Comment: While there can be special cases, ` unnest` is not usually used on list-columns containing "non-standard" classes.  See above.

Comment: So is there no way to unpack a nested listed column with a single item in a way that preserves it?

Comment: Complex objects such as models can frequently contain only one instance of their type so they are placed in lists to allow multiple model instances to be stored with their identifiers and data in a single `tibble`.  That's the benefit of using list-columns.  As I've shown above in the answer, there are special cases such as `interval` in which multiple instances of the object may be stored directly in a tribble column.